# How to efficiently remove/modify data from crossfilter by ID

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I have a performance issue, when removing data points from a crossfilter. Every time I have to do the following:

```
    dimension.filter(tmpReportId);
    var tmpReport = dimension.top(1)[0]; //Because after removal I have to modify the "report" (the data point) and add it back to the crossfilter
    reportsVis.getCrossfilter().remove();
    dimension.filter(null);
```

The problem is, that filter() is applied twice on the whole crossfilter, which makes the operations very expensive on large datasets

Answer (score 0):

`filter(null)` is not an expensive operation as it only clears the filters, it doesn't perform a filter. The [source probably makes things clear](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/blob/master/src/filter.js):

```
function crossfilter_filterAll(values) {
  return [0, values.length];
}
```

`filter(null)` and `filterAll()` are the same operation, and as you can see, it simply returns every value in the dimension.

Comment: This is correct, but the actual problem is ```dimension.filter(tmpReportId);```, which is a relatively expensive operation. There is a Crossfilter [issue on Github](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/issues/109) discussing this problem, and I have a fork mentioned in that issue that provides the ability to directly remove a single record.

Comment: Thank you Ethan, this is actually my real problem. But do you think, the fork you mentioned, improves the performance of removal? I mean, it is a simple filtering function added to remove(), that goes over the whole dataset, isn't it?